# Pass Font from dart to native side

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I have a flutter plugin made in native android, ios.
I want to pass google fonts plugin-based fonts from dart side to the native, so that whatever the fonts user will pass from the dart side, it will be available at the native side. (If possible)
Is there any way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: The fonts you have in Dart, you want to use in native side, right, what's your use case?

Comment: Let's say, I have made a custom view in native, Basically, the font remains the same thoroughly. Now I want to provide more customization with fonts. bold, italic can be handled, but Helvetica, Calibri, can not.